# android: webview show blank screen when i show pdf file from dropbox link

Tags: android

this is my code where show pdf file from shared link. please tell me why it show blank screen

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_wbview);
    mWebView=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_view);

    String weblink="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/107860028/Publishing%20an%20Application%20on%20Google%20Play.pdf";  
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.loadUrl(weblink);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

WebView Can't open pdf You need to use google doc for View Pdf or you can use AdobeReadr Pdf

```
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_wbview);
        mWebView=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_view);

        String weblink="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/107860028/Publishing%20an%20Application%20on%20Google%20Play.pdf"; 

        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
       webview.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=+weblink");
        }
```

Comment: yes you are right using pdf reader and google doc it run fine but my requirement is show pdf from dropbox.

Comment: Do you get the url of pdf form dropbox ?

Comment: in above code "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/107860028/Publishing%20an%20Application%20on%20Google%20Play.pdf is also dummy link of dropbox pdf